# use WordPress Rest API to build a web application

Tags: rest-api

This is fully updated question,

Angular provides two ways to build your wordpress site/application

1. first choice is completely headless application i.e., you won't deal with wordpress dashboard at all. just fetch data required with the help of WP Rest API endpoints, and
2. an angular powered wordpress theme.

Can anybody tell pros and cons of each of the above listed steps

Im not good at angular, so any comprehensive information would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried a e-commerce plugin like WooCommerce ? https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: actually the web application is not woocommerce powered site. it's a fund raising site so user should be able to pay the amount they want from the site.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: This question could be helpful: [Developing Themes with React/Angular](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308310/developing-themes-with-react-angular)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want totally headless application, you should not use wordpress but JS, as with JS you will be able to reuse at least some of the code for both server and client sides.

As for using angular theme.... well the question is still why do you use wordpress at all as you will not get any of the benefits of using plugins to enhance the theme, so what is the added value wordpress gives you, an editor? some server side API you are used to work with? That might be a good enough reasons, but the mileage you will get out of wordpress will be considerably less compare to using a proper theme.

Comment: Im not inteding to use angular powered theme for my client's project but for learning purpose. 
As far as I know, angular applications are SPAs, and if I could leverage power of angular to my single page theme, it would be awesome.
That's all I want to know.
Thanks for answer.

Comment: @maverick wordpress is not an application platform, and building web apps is not one of its strengths. As almost everything else you can bend it enough to be something which it was never intended to be, but it is not going to be fun.

Comment: So, you are saying, best way is to go for completely headless angular application that utilizes wordpress data.

Comment: no, I say that if you want to use JS framework "X" that is intended for building applications, you should not mix wordpress with it unless you have a very good reason (just wanting to play with the framework might be a good enough reason, but it will teach you only how to do client side if you will ever want to build a web app)